# Bug or why? Null being displayed as a space in a string. (FromCharacterCode ASCII)

Tags: fonts, display

I expect `Print[FromCharacterCode[{97, 0, 97}, "ASCII"]]`
output to look the same as `Print[FromCharacterCode[{97, 97}, "ASCII"]]`, but instead it looks like `Print[FromCharacterCode[{97, 32, 97}, "ASCII"]]`.

I see that the "Null space" is being handled differently; `FromCharacterCode[{0}, "ASCII"] == FromCharacterCode[{32}, "ASCII"]` outputs `False`. But why would it display anything in the first place?

Non ASCII seems to work as I expect.`"a"~StringJoin~"\[Null]"~StringJoin~"a"` outputs without displaying a separation but still keeping a Null in the middle. BTW I had to type it in backwards to avoid `\[Nu]`. And it works as I expect with "UTF-8". ex: `FromCharacterCode[{97, 97, 239, 142, 160, 97}, "UTF-8"]`.

I will be switching to UTF-8 but just curious about ASCII.

Comment: `FromCharacterCode[{0}, "ASCII"] == FromCharacterCode[{0}, "ASCII"]` returns `True` for me for all versions I can try now on my Mac, from v12.2 onwards. Also, the string with character code 0 *does* visually look like `"aa"` to me, although I wouldn't expect anything from that visual presentation. What is your Mathematica version and on what platform?

Comment: Typo on that line of code. Edited to read `FromCharacterCode[{0}, "ASCII"] == FromCharacterCode[{32}, "ASCII"]` outputs `False` as expected.

Comment: 12.1.1.0
Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: This may be simply font-specific behaviour. Compare with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190000/3056

Comment: This is also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123736 . Apparently Consolas, used on Windows at least on some versions of Mathematica, shows a space for the zero character, while Source Code Pro, used on Mac on recent versions, doesn't.

Comment: I get the bell with \:260E but not a pixel exact match. I'm willing to chalk this up to a quirk on some user specific software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to be a font issue; both Consolas and Source Code Pro are used as the default code font on at least some Mathematica versions.

[image]

You can check your current set code font:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleHints, "CodeFont"}]

(* "Source Code Pro" *)
```

(That's on my Mac running v13.2.1.)

Only even semi-sensible reason for having different fonts on different platforms that I can come up with is that Consolas might render just a bit better on the Windows platform. No idea if that's the rationale chosen by WRI, though.